# Why is Rails UJS ajax:success bind being called twice?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ujs

I have a simple form:

```
= form_for(posts_path, :id => "new_post", :remote => true) do
  = text_field_tag "post[input]"
  = submit_tag "Post!"
```

I have bound a callback to the `ajax:success` event:

```
$("form#new_post").bind("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, status){
  alert("Post Created!");
});
```

When I click the `Post!` button, the `Post Created` comes up ***twice***. Why?

I'm using Rails 3.1 which by default is using jquery-ujs.

Answer (score 9):

That is because your page is loading `jquery_ujs` code twice in development mode when precompiled assets exist in `/public/assets`.

In development mode javascript requries are loaded with separate tags: `jquery`, `jquery_ujs.js`, `myscripts.js` and finally `applications.js`. The problem happens when precompiled `application.js` exists and is used from `/public/assets` - it contains compilation of all previous files. This is triggered by `assets:precompile` rake task.

The solution is to remove `/public/assets` directory on development then `application.js` is used (from `/app/assets/javascript`) which doesn't include previous files.
Generally doesn't use `assets:precompile` rake task on development.

**Update**

Adding `config.serve_static_assets = false` to `development.rb` also solves problem for me without worrying about `/public/assets`.

Answer (score 5):

A similar thing happened to me upgrading an application from Rails 3.0 to 3.1, it was my mistake. In your

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
```

check that your are not calling twice the rails helpers, i have troubles using

```
//= require_tree .
```

i have removed this and just left

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require myscripts
```

i deleted too `app/assets/javascripts/rails.js`, the file was generated by jquery-rails gem but this is no longer necessary

Comment: I have the same problem, and my javascript assets aren't being included twice. ajax:success is still called twice, even without the require_tree directive active.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem. Removing require_tree helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the gotcha was the

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

option.

Comment: what do you mean? I'm having this problem and also have this line in my development.rb. Should I remove it?

Comment: Actually I found it with the "try and error" approach because I saw in Firebug, that the javascript was loaded twice and therefore the binding was made twice (which resulted in the redundant ajax call). Anyway, I suspect it was because I precompiled the assets locally (because of the deploy to heroku) in combination with the debug = true. Anyway, When I've set the `config.assets.debug = false` it was no longer included twice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It turns out that my problem was also that the script loaded twice. I was moving around dom elements, which caused my script to re-run. I fixed it by running the script after the window.onload event fired.