# "ajax:success" being called twice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using jquery_ujs to send a simple post request. I bound a callback function to the "ajax:success" event. However, this callback is being called twice for each successful post.

I know this is similar to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225600/why-is-rails-ujs-ajaxsuccess-bind-being-called-twice), but I checked my source and it doesn't appear to be loading the jquery_ujs.js file twice (as suggested by many of the responses).

```
    $(".new_item").bind("ajax:success", 
    function(xhr, data, status) 
    {
                 /* this is called twice for each call!*/
    }
```

Anyone have any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Just throwing it out there, but could it be possible that you have two (or more) elements with the `new_item` class?

Comment: nope, just one instance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of a few things are happening.

Either you have multiple elements with .new_item class

```
alert($(".new_item").length);
```

you are sending the ajax request twice

```
alert("Sending Request");
$.ajax(...
```

or you are binding the event twice

```
alert("Binding Event");
$(".new_item").bind("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, status) {
```

*Note: If you are using a modern browser, replace alerts with console.log()*

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It seems to be binding the event twice. In fact, it seems like that entire (html-embedded) script is running twice. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: are you wrapping it or moving it around the dom?

Comment: Yes, I was moving elements around the dom. That was leading to the script getting run twice. I solved this by adding the binding after the window.onload event. Thanks again!

Comment: @KevinB how to deal with multiple elements?

Comment: @truongnm that question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry for ambiguous. I'm in your first case: suppose I've multiple elements with .new_item class, when I got event return on "ajax:success", it call several times (call the previous success events)

Comment: What did you want the behavior to be? because if you bind the event to n elements, it's going to trigger for each one. If you want only a specific one to trigger it, alter your selector so target the specific one.

Comment: @KevinB I have a list of user to follow and unfollow, I can't think of a way to create unique selector for both follow and unfollow button to update after create/destroy success. If I could select the "clicked" element so that I could using "this", that would be so nice, but seeing your comment I think I just need to find a way to create unique id :v

Comment: the ajax;success event might be the wrong tool for the job. Usually it is the wrong tool.