# Rails Ajax form submits twice after first submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this following issue when I submit a post through an ajax form, the first submit will go through correctly but when I try to submit another post (without refreshing the page), it will submit the previous post again and afterwards submit my new post. Due to this I am getting a duplicate post with the same information. What I noticed is that I am getting the correct server request. But when I console.log the amount of submits that I get from the form for one click, I get two submits.

index.html.haml:

```
.row
  .col-md-7.col-md-pull-5
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading.text-center
        Recent Posts
      .panel-body
        = render 'post_form'
      %ul.list-group.all_posts
        = render 'posts'
```

_post_form.html.haml:

```
= simple_form_for(Post.new, action: 'create', remote: true,
                  html: { class: 'form-horizontal'},
                  wrapper: :horizontal_form,
                  wrapper_mappings: { check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes, radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes, file: :horizontal_file_input, boolean: :horizontal_boolean }) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    .post-form-body-pic.inner-inline
      = image_tag(avatar_url(current_employee), class: "avatar50")
    .post-form-content.inner-inline
      = f.input :content, input_html: {rows: "3"}, label: false, :placeholder => "Share something with everyone..."
  = f.button :submit, value: "Post", class: "btn btn-danger pull-right new"
```

application.js:

```
#
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require moment
#= require fullcalendar
#= require bootstrap-sprockets
#= require turbolinks
#= require paloma
#= require staticpages
#= require dashboards
#= require calendar
#= require trade_center
#= require profile_account


ready = ->
    $("#trade-center").click ->
        $("#trade").slideToggle("500", ->)




$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

post_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to  :js

  def create
    @post = profile.posts.create!(posts_params)
  end

  private

  def posts_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:profile_id, :content)
  end

  def post
    @post = profile.posts.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

create.js:

```
$("form#new_post").bind("ajax:complete", function(){
    $("textarea#post_content").val("");
    html = "<%= j render '/dashboards/post', :locals => {:post => @post} %>"    
    $("ul.all_posts").prepend(html).slideDown("slow");
    delete html
});
```

/dashboards/_post.html.haml:

```
%li.list-group-item
  .post-profile
    = image_tag "http://static.nfl.com/static/content/public/static/img/fantasy/transparent/200x200/WOO661523.png?01AD=3n6mqKw_qL00dpnfbGHt_psO6gNStPFmrhrEnOUuVho8CHdcw_9g8Ow&01RI=0D206B0E41C6CD5&01NA=", class: "avatar50 inner-inline"
    .post-name.inner-inline
      = "#{@post.profile.fname} #{@post.profile.lname}"
      %p
        %span 
          = "Posted on #{@post.created_at.to_date.to_s(:long)}"
    %span.dropdown.pull-right
      %span.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-down{:class => "[ ]"}
      %ul.dropdown-menu{:role => "menu"}
        %li{:role => "presentation"}
          %a{:href => "#", :role => "menuitem", :tabindex => "-1"} Edit
        %li{:role => "presentation"}
          %a{:href => "#", :role => "menuitem", :tabindex => "-1"} Another action
        %li{:role => "presentation"}
          %a{:href => "#", :role => "menuitem", :tabindex => "-1"} Something else here
        %li.divider{:role => "presentation"}
        %li.btn-xs.btn-danger{:role => "presentation"}
          = link_to "Delete this post", @post, :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => "Are you sure?"},:remote => true, :class => 'delete_post'
  %p.post-context<>
    = "#{@post.content}."
```

Comment: Can you post the form code which you are calling this partial?

Comment: And also please post your `application.js`

Comment: Hey pavan, I have added the application.js and the index.html file where the form is called

Answer (score 0):

If you have `//= require jquery_ujs` in your `application.js` and if you are included `<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/jquery_ujs.js" %>` in your ***form code(the form which you are calling the partial)*** then remove it. This could be the reason for the form ***submitting twice***.

Comment: No, in my application.html i call my javascript file like this                             = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try emptying the @post variable like this :

```
def create
 @post = nil
 @post = profile.posts.create!(posts_params)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the issue was not the form being sumbitted twice but my bind ajax:success call that was being called twice. I am not sure if its a proper way to do it but since rails will deal with validation, I just decided to remove the bind that I had on my form and just execute the JavaScript that I want. It works perfectly...for now.

Oh I want to also mention that I have tried looking at these threads on ajax:success being called twice and nothing worked: [Why is Rails UJS ajax:success bind being called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225600/why-is-rails-ujs-ajaxsuccess-bind-being-called-twice), ["ajax:success" being called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017890/ajaxsuccess-being-called-twice)

Here is the modification of create.js:

```
$("textarea#post_content").val("");
    html = "<%= j render '/dashboards/post', :locals => {:post => @post} %>"    
    $("ul.all_posts").prepend(html).slideDown("slow");
    delete html
```